# after showing bootstrap modal from the sucess function of ajax, after a particular time call a javascript function

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, bootstrap-modal

//ajax function call success function in an external javascript file

```
success: function(data) {
                $('#edtModal').show();
           }
```

//at jsp page

```
$('#edtModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
                    alert("hi");
                    var ex = getTime('tt');
                    window.setTimeout(alertFunc, ex);
                });
```

//but the above jquery code in jsp not working

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: no error in console@Mayank Pandeyz

Comment: @MayankPandeyz no error

Comment: You want to call a function in ajax response after some time ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz :no i don't want to call a function in ajax response.i want to display a modal if ajax is sucess and in jsp page when the modal is shown i need set timeout and when time reaches a function named "alertFunc" need to call

Comment: OK, so where are you stuck ?

Comment: modal is showing in jsp but the jquery to get time and to set timeout and to call function alertFunc ie;$('#edtModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {} not working

Comment: @MayankPandeyz :can you provide any solution?can you tell which are the script and css files i need to link?

Comment: Cimy: try this - https://jsfiddle.net/cubttgow/5/

Comment: @MayankPandeyz :in the above example the modal is showing on document.ready() can you provide the  sample code to call a function to get time expiry for that modal from database table and when time reaches  ,no need to hide the modal but show an alert function and depend on user click on alert we need to decide whether to hide or show modal again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138310/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-cimy-riya).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//at jsp page
//when below button is clicked

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-primary edt" title="Edit" onclick="setValues('${row.a}', '${row.b}', '${row.C}', '${row.d}')"  role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
```

//it will set values onclick and call a ajax function and the sucess function of //ajax shows a modal

```
success: function(data) {
                $('#edtModal').show();
           }
```

//in jsp when button is clicked the bellow jquery also works but it shows only //if ajax is sucess,so it works like shown.bs.modal

```
 $('.edt').click(function() {

                        var ex = countDown('xxx');
                        setTimeout(function alertFunc() {
                            var r = confirm("Your Time Expired,Do you want to continue");
                            if (r === true) {
                                window.setTimeout(alertFunc, ex);
                            } else {
                                var url = "hide";
                                window.location = url;
                            }
                        }, ex);
                    });
                });
```